# En Java, Castear "this" a una Interface que implemento, ¿es mala práctica?

Tags: java, interfaz

quería saber si dada una clase en JAVA, que implementa N interfaces , se considera mala práctica castear el valor de this, para que, el objeto que reciba el mensaje, lo interprete directamente como una instancia de tipo Interfaz y no Foo. (Debido a que el receptor de mensaje implementa el metodo notify sobrecargado con I1,I2,I3)

Ej:

```
public class Foo extends DadClass implements I1, I2, I3 {
    @Override
    public int method(int arg1) {
        if (arg1+1 == 2){
            another_class.notify((I1) this, duenio); //Suponemos another_class previamente definido
            return 1;
        }
        return 2;
    }
}
```

A su vez, en el ejemplo, consideran que se rompe el principio de única responsabilidad, debido a que se envia una notificación a another_class y se devuelve un valor?
Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

***Antes que todo:*** no puedes usar la palabra `class` como identificador puesto que esta es una palabra reservada del lenguaje.

En este caso no es necesario el *casting* puesto que tu clase `Class` a su vez también "es de tipo" `I1`, por lo que no habrán errores de compilación por pasar directamente `this` al método `notify()`.

```
class.notify(this, duenio);// esto es correcto
```

Los `castings` (generalmente) se usan cuando en tiempo de compilación no es posible conocer el tipo de un objeto.

```
// Supongamos que de la clase Persona heredan Profesor y Estudiante
// y con la llamada a loadAll() obtenemos instancias de ambos
List<Persona> personas = servicioPersonas.loadAll();

for (Persona p : personas) {
    if (p instanceof Estudiante) {
        // Este método espera una instancia de Estudiante
        notificarEstudiante((Estudiante) p)
    }
}
```

Sobre el principio de responsabilidad única te comento que no tiene nada que ver con el hecho de enviar y/o recibir valores, notificaciones o cualquier otra cosa, sino, de que las clases tengan una sola función; y sin ver el código completo de la clase es difícil determinarlo.

Esto es un poco controversial puesto que el principio no define que se entiende por "reponsabilidad". De ahí que no haya concenso y haya a quienes metamos varios método en una misma clase y haya otro que tener más de uno lo consideren romper el principio.

***ACTUALIZACION: Producto a edición de la pregunta con más detalles***

Si, como aclaras, el receptor del mensaje tiene el método `notify()` sobrecargado para varias de las intefaces que implementa la clase `Foo` entonces ya no estamos hablando de buena/mala práctica sino que es **obligatorio** usar el *casting* puesto que de otro modo la llamada al método es ambigua y el compilador no podrá determinar cuál de todos los métodos debe llamar.

Comment: Gracias, ahí corregí lo de Class y aclaré un par de temas! 
Lo que sucede es que no puedo hacer "class.notify(this, duenio);", debido a que class implementa el notify sobercargados con I1, I2 e I3. Por eso preguntaba si era mala práctica el casteo.